# localPlayerDidSelectChallenge method gets called even if player doesn't tap GKChallenge banner

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, game-center, gamekit

When a player receives a `GKChallenge`, the `GKChallengeEventHandler` calls `localPlayerDidReceiveChallenge` on the delegate implementing the `GKChallengeEventHandlerDelegate` protocol, then immediately after, calls `localPlayerDidSelectChallenge`, every time.

The docs say that for `localPlayerDidSelectChallenge` to be called, one of two things must happen:

- The user taps the challenge banner
- The user opens the app in response to receiving a challenge notification

But it seems to be called every time, even if the app is open already and without the user ever touching the banner!